# Material-ui component Checkbox handler does not set the state - V.5.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, components

s, I made a component "Checkbox" to be used in others forms of my app, but the state does not update after click. It works and get checked at the DOM, but the state doesn't change, it remains 'false'. I'm using Material-ui v.5.0 and React 18.0.1, all helps will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance. I don't know  what mistake I'm doing. I'm a newbie in React. Below follows my codes. It should be a component, where I will use in another form. After checked, I want it to become disabled. Thanks folks.

```js
// CardNotes Component
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import {  DeleteOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import Checkbox  from './Checkbox';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    test: {
        border: (note) => {
            if (note.status == 'Urgente'){
                return '1px solid red'
            }
            return '1px solid blue'
        }
    }
})


export default function CardNotes({ note, handleDelete }){
    
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    console.log('checkbox', checked)
    

    const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
      };

     
    const classes = useStyles(note)

    return( // receiving props from Notes
        <div>
            <Card elevation={3} className={classes.test}>
                <CardHeader 
                titleTypographyProps={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                  }}
                 action={
                    <IconButton onClick={()=> handleDelete(note.id) }>
                    <DeleteOutlined />
                  </IconButton>
                  
                 }
        
                 title={note.title}
                 subheader={note.status}

                />
                
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="display2" color="textSecondary">
                        {note.details}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                 <Box ml={2}>
                <Checkbox 
                 label="Resolvido"
                  checked={checked}
                  onChange={ (e) => setChecked(e.target.checked)}>
                 </Checkbox>
                 </Box>

            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```html
// checkbox component
import React from 'react'
import {FormControl , FormControlLabel} from '@mui/material';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';



export default function Chekbox (props) {

const { resolved, handleChange } = props;


  return (
    <FormControl>
        <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox
            checked={resolved}
            color="primary"
            onChange={handleChange}
        />}
        label='Resolvido'
        />

    </FormControl>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check names of props you pass to CheckBox Component.
there are differences between those and props you type in CheckBox file

Comment: Amirreza Mojarad, I've corrected and did not work. The problems still the same. It doesn't  change the state.

Comment: share it on codesandbox, then i can take a look, maybe i can find the bug

Comment: Amirreza I couldn't find your name on codesandbox. So, I copied  the link. https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-neumann-xvqbyh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: chechk your codesandbox
it doesnt work properly

Comment: Here is link your name doesn't show to me: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-neumann-xvqbyh?from-embed